# A function that returns several vectors in the mutate section

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a problem that puzzles me. What is the easiest (and most elegant) way to program a function to use in a mutation section that returns several vectors.

I'll give an example. Let's say I have such a function.

```
f1 = function(x, n){
  y1 = rep(NA, length(x))
  y2 = rep(NA, length(x))
  y3 = rep(NA, length(x))
  y4 = rep(NA, length(x))
  for(i in (n+1):(length(x)-n)){
    idx = (i-n):(i+n)
    y1[i] = sin(mean(x[idx])/max(x[idx]))
    y2[i] = cos(mean(x[idx])/max(x[idx]))
    y3[i] = tan(mean(x[idx])/max(x[idx]))
    y4[i] = 1/tan(mean(x[idx])/max(x[idx]))
  }
  data.frame(
    y1 = y1,
    y2 = y2,
    y3 = y3,
    y4 = y4
  )
}
```

Please do not analyze its mathematical sense, this is just an example.
As you can see, this function takes one vector and returns four vectors of the same length.
If I would like to use this function in the mutation section, the function will be called four times. Unfortunately, with a long input vector, it will take a long time.

Here is an example.

```
n = 10000
df = tibble(
  key = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), n),
  val = rep(rnorm(n), 4)
)

f1test = function(df) df %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(
    y1 = f1(val, 100) %>% pull(y1),
    y2 = f1(val, 100) %>% pull(y2),
    y3 = f1(val, 100) %>% pull(y3),
    y4 = f1(val, 100) %>% pull(y4)
  )
f1test(df)
```

When looking for a solution, I had a slightly different idea to return all four vectors at once and then separate them somehow.
So I created a second example function that does the same computation, it only differs in the way it returns the result.

```
f2 = function(x, n){
  ret = rep(NA, length(x))
  for(i in (n+1):(length(x)-n)){
    idx = (i-n):(i+n)
    ret[i] = paste(
      sin(mean(x[idx])/max(x[idx])),
      cos(mean(x[idx])/max(x[idx])),
      tan(mean(x[idx])/max(x[idx])),
      1/tan(mean(x[idx])/max(x[idx])), sep = ";")
  }
  ret
}
```

Using such functions may look like this:

```
f2test = function(df) df %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(ret = f2(val, 100)) %>% 
  separate(ret, paste0("y", 1:4), sep=";", convert = TRUE)  
f2test(df)
```

You can see right away that the latter should be faster. And it really is for n = 1000, the version with f2 is approximate 2 times faster.

For n = 10000, it is four times faster.

Now my question. Does anyone know a better (and more elegant) way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However you form your function, there's no need to calculate four times with

```r
mutate(
    y1 = f1(val, 100) %>% pull(y1),
    y2 = f1(val, 100) %>% pull(y2),
    y3 = f1(val, 100) %>% pull(y3),
    y4 = f1(val, 100) %>% pull(y4)
  )
```

You can `mutate` (without assignment) something that returns a frame:

```r
f1 <- function(x) data.frame(mysin = sin(x), mycos = cos(x), mytan = tan(x))
mtcars %>%
  mutate(f1(cyl)) %>%
  head
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   mysin   mycos  mytan
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 -0.2794  0.9602 -0.291
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 -0.2794  0.9602 -0.291
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 -0.7568 -0.6536  1.158
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 -0.2794  0.9602 -0.291
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  0.9894 -0.1455 -6.800
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 -0.2794  0.9602 -0.291
```

If you want to assign names in the process, then you can do

```r
mtcars %>%
  mutate(setNames(f1(cyl), c("A","B","C"))) %>%
  head
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb       A       B      C
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 -0.2794  0.9602 -0.291
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 -0.2794  0.9602 -0.291
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 -0.7568 -0.6536  1.158
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 -0.2794  0.9602 -0.291
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  0.9894 -0.1455 -6.800
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 -0.2794  0.9602 -0.291
```

This is obviously a simplification compared with your `f1`, my point is that you can natively use all columns in the returned value without having to figure out how to separate them.

This might make your other function

```r
f1test = function(df) df %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(f1(val, 100))
```

(with or without `setNames`).

Comment: Yes! This is the solution I was looking for.
`df %>% group_by(key) %>%  mutate(f1(val, 100))`
Simple and very elegant! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `split` and make this more faster`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(split(df$val, df$key), f1, n = 15, .id = 'key')
```

or use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(split(df$val, df$key), f1, n = 15), idcol = 'key')
```

#### Benchmarks

```
#OP's function
> system.time(f1test(df))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.589   0.170   3.748 
> system.time(map_dfr(split(df$val, df$key), f1, n = 15, .id = 'key'))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.606   0.029   0.635 
> system.time(rbindlist(lapply(split(df$val, df$key), f1, n = 15), idcol = 'key'))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.591   0.024   0.614
```